# How do I perform this specific excel vlookup task

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two tables

and I want to transfer values from columns "Val2" to "Val trans". The shown tables are simplified replication of the actual tables which have hundreds of rows. ideally a simple vlookup should help but i have some cases where dates differ by a day or so (which shouldn't matter for this task). for instance the 2nd entry has 31/10/2015 in one table and 30/10/2015. a vlookup wont help in this case, how do I get around this issue. I should still see 0 for 30/10/2015 under column "Val trans". Some kind of vlookup based on mm/yyyy might do the trick I suppose.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(search_criteria, range, 2, TRUE)` should do it for you.

Comment: Specifying TRUE for VLOOKUP will find an "approximate" date which means a date "on or before" the one being looked up. Therefore, if you look for the end of the month in a list of monthly dates the last date in the specified month will be found (30th instead of 31st). However, this won't work the other way around (31st instead of 30th) and it won't work if entries are missing because it will return the September date if October isn't in the list. In that case I would recommend to convert the dates in the Lookup column to last days of their respective months before running VLOOKUP with FALSE.

Comment: thanks guys, I agree with @Variatus, as using "TRUE" in the lookup didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering 50 rows and
Date in col A,
val2 in col B,
Date in col C,
val1 in col D,
trans in col E.

Please try below Array formula in column E with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
=VLOOKUP(MIN(IF(ABS($A$2:$A$50-C2)=MIN(ABS($A$2:$A$50-C2)),IF(ABS($A$2:$A$50-C2)< C2*0.05,$A$2:$A$50,9.99999999999999E+307))),$A$2:$B$50,2,0)
```

This makes a tolerance of + or - 5%. You can change as per your need.